# SQL Update based on a specific count from a child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Using Microsoft Azure SQL
I have the following select query working.
I need a update where I set wd.delete_requested = true for any records with a stopsCount = 0.
So in other words, the stop_detail is related to the Driver_Wave_Ticket_Table.  I need to flag for deletion any wave ticket record that does not have any stop_detail records.

```
    SELECT wd.Id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stop_Detail sd WHERE sd.wave_ticket_detail_Id = wd.Id) stopsCount
FROM Driver_Wave_Ticket_Detail wd
WHERE  wd.wave_ticket_date = '1901-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND wd.delete_requested IS NULL
AND wd.opened_utc IS  NULL
ORDER BY wd.id, stopsCount
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm . . . I'm thinking `not exists`:

```
update wd
    set delete_requested = 1
    from Driver_Wave_Ticket_Detail wd
    where not exists (select 1
                      from Stop_Detail sd 
                      where sd.wave_ticket_detail_Id = wd.Id
                     ) and
          wd.wave_ticket_date = '1901-01-01 00:00:00.000' and
          wd.delete_requested IS NULL and
          wd.opened_utc IS  NULL;
```

In general, `not exists` is faster than doing an aggregation and checking that the result is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I'm thinking of using a case statement for this scenario:

```
SELECT
a.Id,
a.stopsCount,
CASE WHEN stopsCount = 0 THEN True else FALSE end as delete_flag
FROM
(SELECT wd.Id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stop_Detail sd WHERE sd.wave_ticket_detail_Id = wd.Id) stopsCount
FROM Driver_Wave_Ticket_Detail wd
WHERE  wd.wave_ticket_date = '1901-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND wd.delete_requested IS NULL
AND wd.opened_utc IS  NULL) a
ORDER BY
a.Id,
a.stopsCount
```